# How to assign the whole line except several columns to an array index

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

I operate three similar text files all contain 8 fields and look like:

```
File1:
145794  MEG -0.249553181556742  10.7024481844394    -2.66596894783271   0.00786178413495372 0.0601441357290167  -2.83690413867182    
144476  ACK 0.290866506987197   8.80253427197157    2.61876968039967    0.00902429557487308 0.0658077662524982  -2.9436012186193
213406  ANX -0.396398224155449  2.29892473132668    -2.67676795263515   0.00761548692081231 0.0589487734598402  -3.08353414541367

File2:
145794  MEG -0.287372579587733  9.41247425082302    -1.97898175477022   0.0490956252910287  0.309158729905081   -4.08090215553766
144476  ACK 0.298963990141891   6.98503289865222    1.45624070508412    0.146786315195169   0.492695221406182   -4.92059721623638
144161  ZCH -0.0427538540851567 9.7901544903037 -1.06263504958352   0.288330305382714   0.545733380330329   -5.69279245581735

File3:
145794  MEG -0.0565314859334139 11.3691862642502    -0.581110824476088  0.56158942073398    0.792421821608773   -5.90344886517337
144476  ACK 0.25574693016845    9.21536363194302    1.89547789943679    0.0589622388458051  0.247543472790285   -4.34643638570199
144161  ZCH -0.0618203872359407 9.77324184266448    -1.14042457462774   0.254992692808188   0.539040584775996   -5.42726538436031
```

I want to merge these three files with the values in the first and second fields matching, so my code will look like:

```
awk '
  FNR==1{
    f++
  }
  f==1{
    g[$1]=$0; 
    next
  }
  f==2{
    if($1 in g) g[$1]=g[$1]"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8; 
    else g[$1]=$0
  }
  f==3{
    if($1 in g) g[$1]=g[$1]"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8; 
    else g[$1]=$0
  }
  END{
    for (i in g) print g[i]
  }
' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > merged.txt
```

The expected output:

```
145794  MEG -0.249553181556742  10.7024481844394    -2.66596894783271   0.00786178413495372 0.0601441357290167  -2.83690413867182   -0.287372579587733  9.41247425082302    -1.97898175477022   0.0490956252910287  0.309158729905081   -4.08090215553766   -0.0565314859334139 11.3691862642502    -0.581110824476088  0.56158942073398    0.792421821608773   -5.90344886517337
144476  ACK 0.290866506987197   8.80253427197157    2.61876968039967    0.00902429557487308 0.0658077662524982  -2.9436012186193    0.298963990141891   6.98503289865222    1.45624070508412    0.146786315195169   0.492695221406182   -4.92059721623638   0.25574693016845    9.21536363194302    1.89547789943679    0.0589622388458051  0.247543472790285   -4.34643638570199
213406  ANX -0.396398224155449  2.29892473132668    -2.67676795263515   0.00761548692081231 0.0589487734598402  -3.08353414541367
144161  ZCH -0.0427538540851567 9.7901544903037 -1.06263504958352   0.288330305382714   0.545733380330329   -5.69279245581735   -0.0618203872359407 9.77324184266448    -1.14042457462774   0.254992692808188   0.539040584775996   -5.42726538436031
```

But the

```
g[$1]=g[$1]"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6"\t"$7"\t"$8
```

is too long, is there any cleaner way to replace this?

Comment: post a fragments from your 3 files and expected result

Comment: OK, I have modified my question

Comment: what should be the result if some of input files does not match by the 1st field?

Comment: Like the "213406  ANX" in file 1, it doesn't appear in file2 & 3, so the row started with "213406  ANX" in the result file only contains the numbers from that row in file 1. I just want to integrate these 3 files and the rows which have common 1st and 2ed fields will be combined. If some rows have no common 1st and 2ed fields, they will also appear in the result file.

Comment: Actually, I just want to make sure if any row has no common 1st (ID) and 2ed field (symbol for that ID) exists in my files. Then I found the files share all IDs and symbols (they have the same number of lines).

Comment: is it OK if the output won't be ordered?

Comment: Oops, I still don't know how to output an ordered result using this kind of method, an ordered one (for 1st column) is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`cat`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
cat file[123].txt \
| awk '{ k = $1 OFS $2 }
       !(k in a){ keys[++c] = k }
       { a[k] = (a[k]? a[k] OFS : "") $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 OFS $7 OFS $8; }
       END{ 
           for (i=1; i<=c; i++) print keys[i], a[keys[i]] 
       }' OFS='\t'
```

- `k = $1 OFS $2` - crucial key made by combination of the 1st field `$1` and 2nd field `$2`
- `!(k in a){ keys[++c] = k }` - `keys` is an array containing group keys `k` in their initial order
- `a[k] = (a[k]? a[k] OFS : "") $3 OFS $4 ...` - capture/append all the needed field values related to a certain group `k`

---

The output:

```
145794  MEG -0.249553181556742  10.7024481844394    -2.66596894783271   0.00786178413495372 0.0601441357290167  -2.83690413867182   -0.287372579587733  9.41247425082302    -1.97898175477022   0.0490956252910287  0.309158729905081   -4.08090215553766   -0.0565314859334139 11.3691862642502    -0.581110824476088  0.56158942073398    0.792421821608773   -5.90344886517337
144476  ACK 0.290866506987197   8.80253427197157    2.61876968039967    0.00902429557487308 0.0658077662524982  -2.9436012186193    0.298963990141891   6.98503289865222    1.45624070508412    0.146786315195169   0.492695221406182   -4.92059721623638   0.25574693016845    9.21536363194302    1.89547789943679    0.0589622388458051  0.247543472790285   -4.34643638570199
213406  ANX -0.396398224155449  2.29892473132668    -2.67676795263515   0.00761548692081231 0.0589487734598402  -3.08353414541367
144161  ZCH -0.0427538540851567 9.7901544903037 -1.06263504958352   0.288330305382714   0.545733380330329   -5.69279245581735   -0.0618203872359407 9.77324184266448    -1.14042457462774   0.254992692808188   0.539040584775996   -5.42726538436031
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add some explanations on the 3 & 4 lines?

Comment: @MagicPants, see my explanation